The Minimum Points To Determine A Monotone Boolean Function
Given a positive integer $n$, two players, Player Alice and Player Bob, play the following game:

Alice first chooses a function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ that is non-decreasing with respect to each input, and Bob is aware of this property.
Bob then provides a sequence of inputs $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, where each $a_i \in \{0,1\}$, and Alice responds with the value of $f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$.
Based on Alice's responses, Bob decides what to ask next.

Denote the minimum number of sequences $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ that Bob must query to ensure he can determine $f$ as $c(n)$. I want to find $c(n)$.
I guess $c(n)=C_{n+1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}$.
I have proved by contradiction that $c(n)\ge C_{n+1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}$. Assume Bob queries fewer than $C_{n+1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}$ sequences of $a_i$. Alice has the following strategy to make Bob wrong:

Define $f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=\begin{cases}0, & \text{if there are }\le\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\text{ ones in }a_i \\ 1, & \text{if there are }>\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\text{ ones in }a_i\end{cases}$
Since Bob has asked fewer than $C_{n+1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}$ sequences of $a_i$, there must exist at least one sequence of $a_i$ such that:


It contains exactly $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ or $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1$ ones (there are precisely $C_{n+1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}$ such sequences of $a_i$);




Bob has not queried this particular sequence of $a_i$.


Modify the value of $f$ for this sequence of $a_i$, it is not hard to verify that the new $f$ remains monotonic.
Bob cannot distinguish between the original $f$ and the modified $f$, leading to a contradiction!

I have verified that $c(n)=C_{n+1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}$ when $n \leq 4$ by enumeration.
Is my answer correct? If it is, how to construct Bob's strategy?

What does nondecreasing function mean in the context of Boolean functions? What’s the order on the inputs?

@Pranay It's the product partial order. So $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\leq (b_1,\dots,b_n)$ iff $a_i\leq b_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. See here.

@AlexKruckman I see, thanks!
